# Avoid calling a function twice

Tags: python, function

I have the following situation in Python:

```
def func_0(x):
    # connects to a third party software
    val_1, val_2 = output_extracted_from_a_third_party_software
    return [val_1, val_2]

def func_1(x):
    return func_0()[0]

def func_2(x):
    return func_0()[1]

another_third_party_func(func_1, func_2) # this is a function that I cannot modify
```

Facts:

- It is not possible for me to modify func_0 because it just extracts the output of a third party software (a computationally expensive process).
- As a part of an algorithm, I have to pass func_1 and func_2 **as 2 separate arguments** into another third party library.

I'm looking for a more efficient way to define func_1 and func_2, so that I avoid calling func_0 twice.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
Memorization doesn't work in this case because x has to be a numpy array.

Comment: memoization is the term you probably need to google

Comment: `func_1` and `func_2` should *take the values it needs as arguments*, then you can do somethng liek `val1, val2 = func_0(x)` then simply call `y1 = func_1(x, val1)` and `y2 = func_2(x, val2)`

Comment: @Moshmet it would probably good if you edited your question with more real code as people are getting hung up the fact that you are returning a list and that val1 and val2 are not defined

Comment: Your code is confusing: You're not calling `func_0` from `func_1` and `func_2` but are rather treating it like an array, and you don't use the values of `x` passed to `func_1` and `func_2`.  †he key to your question seems to be if you can call `func_0` just once, but it is unclear if you want to call it only once with the same value for the `x` parameter it takes or with two different `x` values.  If you want to call it with the same `x` value, then you can use some sort of caching, and @JoranBeasley's answer is a great way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

you can use memoization to solve this ... i think just the builtin LRU cache would work

```
@functools.lru_cache
def func_0(x):
    do something using x
    return [val_1, val_2]
```

of coarse this only works if `x` is the same in both calls ...

you can see it work as follows

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache
def func_0(x):
    print("do something using x")
    return [x,x+1]

print(func_0(5)) # see print 'about do something using x'
print(func_0(6)) # see print 'about do something using x'
print(func_0(5)) # DO NOT see print 'about do something using x'
```

Comment: I re-formulated the question, so that people don't get confused.
Do you think it is clearer now?

Comment: Unfortunaltey it doesn't work because x is a numpy array (unhashable type).

Answer (score -1):

Could you be looking for Tuple unpacking?

Comment: i believe you are trying to help him solve the wrong problem

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.  This should be in a comment.